# Kotlin/Ktor: "closing chunk expected" when requesting a web page

Tags: http, kotlin, apache-httpclient-4.x, ktor, apache-httpasyncclient

I'm trying to request a simple HTTP resource in Kotlin using Ktor's client library (1.4.1):

```kotlin
//
// DomainSpecificObjectFactory.kt
//

object DomainSpecificObjectFactory {
    private val client = HttpClient {
        UserAgent("some user agent string")
    }

    suspend fun fromUrl(url: String): DomainSpecificObject = coroutineScope {
        val pageHtml = client.get<String>(url)
        val document = Jsoup.parse(pageHtml)
        val objProps = getDomainSpecificProperties(document)

        DomainSpecificObject(objProps)
    }
}

//
// SomeOtherFile.kt
//

val obj = DomainSpecificObjectFactory.fromUrl("http://example.com/bla")
```

However, I get this exception:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
```

Should I be configuring the HTTP client any differently?

Comment: Looks like it is a server problem... Will it work with `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"` URL for instance?

Comment: It may be; but even if it is, what can I do? The very same page loads just fine in a browser.

Comment: Have you tried other [engines](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html)?

Comment: Will it work if you will not reuse HttpClient instance? 

```suspend fun fromUrl(url: String): DomainSpecificObject = coroutineScope {
    HttpClient {
        UserAgent("some user agent string")
    }.use {
        val pageHtml = it.get<String>(url)
        val document = Jsoup.parse(pageHtml)
        val objProps = getDomainSpecificProperties(document)

        DomainSpecificObject(objProps)
    }
}```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @МихаилНафталь! didn't work out - I tried the CIO engine, same error - tried to not re-use the client, same error

Comment: Does this page loads fine with `curl` utility?

Comment: Yes, loads just fine.

Comment: And what about [Curl engine](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#curl)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with Ktor 1.5.2